# Wordpress- Displaying and layering custom fields/posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am somewhat new to both Wordpress and PHP, and I wanted to get advice on the best way to tackle my problem as I have had little luck doing it successfully so far.

There are two jobs I want to handle:

First of all, I want to have a conditional include on my home page that does the following;

Find a custom post type home_content (only ever going to be 1 post, which is ID 76 - if that helps)
Display 3 custom fields from that post... the values for today_on front_widget_a & front_widget_b

(I guess a secondary question would be - can I even pass shortcode through a custom field, because that's what those widgets are being generated from, is shortcode from a plug-in)

That's pretty much it.  I've tried various combination of get_posts and get_post_meta without much success.  Either I get some syntax errors I can't figure out (and trust me I've combed my code many times for missing semi-colons and the like).  That or I get a result that makes no sense.

The second one is a bit more difficult.

Basically trying to turn a part of my Wordpress into a bit of a CMS-style feature.  Basically, I have 2 additional custom post types, one called tag_page_layout and one called tag_page_data.

When a Tag in a post is clicked on, I want the Tag page to grab custom field 1 from the tag_page_layout, and then a couple custom fields worth of data from tag_page_data.

I probably wouldn't even need the two post types if I took the time to learn the PHP or HTML code for making tabs, but again, I'm using a plug-in for Wordpress shortcode (which, if you see above - I'm not even sure is going to work right - of course if its not I'm willing to make multiple of these 'layout' posts so each [tab:NAME] shortcode bit is in it's own post-content area.

So... the tag page will basically have a big bit of code that runs before the loop.... it knows its on a tag page so it starts loading Custom Field 1 from the tag_page_layout, which is essentially a bit of code that starts up a Tab-separated data presentation area.  Then it's got to take the tag clicked and match it with the same tag ID from custom post type #2 - the tag_page_data group.  Then it will grab the first 3 or so fields from that page, swap back to the layout post, throw another custom field from there to start another tab, and so on and so forth, until a [tab:END] and it runs the loop.

I could include all my various attempts and bits of code that never worked or half worked, but I've been around so many circles trying to construct this.  Like I said, my coding knowledge is limited but I can usually feel my way around, however these finer points of trying to make Wordpress a little more CMS-like seem to be harder for me to grasp.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you are probably going to get better results by splitting these questions up. It makes it easier to answer and in the future, people with a similar issue can more easily find an answer without having to ask.

Comment: And, I think you are right, you wouldn't need to have the custom post types if you used PHP directly; I'm not certain what WP shortcode is, but I'm guessing is another layer on top of PHP to simplify it.  But, PHP, especially as WP has set it, isn't that difficult to use and there is probably more documentation on WP/PHP than WP/shortcode

Comment: I think you're somewhat confused about what custom post types are supposed to do. All of these things can be done with very basic templating in WordPress. Custom post types are not at all what you seem to think they are.

Answer (score 1):

As far as using shortcodes in custom fields go, this should help you out, where XXX is your custom field name.

```
<?php
$var = apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'XXX', $single = true) );
echo $var;
?>
```

This apply's the standard filters wordpress automatically runs on regular post content, allowing it to process your custom field and convert the shortcode.